# How to make the underscore for field looks evenly?

Tags: html, css

Now I am create a html to just duplicate the word file. And how to achieve the following outlook?[This one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h167L.png)

I use underscore to act like the field. How can I make the end of each line to be equal? One more thing to remark is that, this div should be `style="padding-left: 200px;"`, comparing to the whole file.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, Alex!  Can you please share what you've tried so far?  Remember, we're here to help with questions but we're not a code-on-demand service.  :)

Comment: ...I stand corrected.

Comment: You could use text fields and then use CSS to style them as just a line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alex, to achieve this, you'll need to use some form of layout element. There are a couple options, but the most prevalent today is [Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes).

To use Flexbox to achieve this, you could do something like:

HTML:

```
<form class="form">
  <div class="row">
    <label>First Field</label>
    <span>
      <input>    
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <label>Second Field</label>
    <span>
      <input>    
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <label>Third and Final Field</label>
    <span>
      <input>    
    </span>
  </div>
</form>
```

CSS:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.row span {
  flex: 1;
  display: block;
}

.row span input {
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 5px;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  background: transparent;
  outline: none !important;
}
```

See [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wf15kx6h/)